# Jmeter VIEWSTATE Count changes dynamically

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

I am facing a Unique challenging situation. I am working on developing a J meter script for ASP .net application. When i do the recording it creates 127 view states and provided a count as well. But the count can increase or decrease based on the user we log in. i tried manually correlating all the values and script is successfully if it returns 127 but fails if count changes.

I need some insights

1. How can i can correlate all the view states with a single regular expression. As Viewstate starts from __VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="xyz" /> , __VIEWSTATE1" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="abc" />.... to __VIEWSTATE127" id="__VIEWSTATE127" value="123" />.
2. How can i construct the request payload based on the count of view state.

POST data:
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=4CEEB656&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section1%24txtNMSJob=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=A%2FRl38k0Tgiybffo1OLbt4qZXQWjv1lB3ieW87A0ZUFl6kwwCk58Jlu37%2FRGvuVMJ2mtz5zOwu3OcPtPR%2F7mLPde90%2F873dEQtvrv7TtKuhyAP%2Be4hAITEQBzZIFgRhowms6qoOcelX7AMa8idlVaf5%2FuZLSuIGgh%2BRfeooDg9b3HT3tDkY9YSoHTE9VgDNbZu6WyDtVmkBmd5xhXftET8sTVD58JhP3UycdEZYf7WQxhkHlPLUlGPC5CzKS8dhi2G9iYY2XTJsaNjwFfxEGv5uW4oSZ9KhY0rX3Q7DWwgHGXRI%2FNFieBAhziGCDIwqvTAVN%2B6o6TF1CJBhMcv8tizLxMFHa5TB5Z6KzN78luRc6J3E88IdCajbBzaT13c%2BqjrO0UjPZf2ypDl7%2FXLh1YdJNVBIl19UuftQoZ%2FZM9mFl8HBNKSjEe%2BQh9DqMNdi5oqcjd4UjYGl4cyrHn%2BzwPvfjnfeiPX1lNGrnzykeIUPYoV58hygZ&ctl00_ctl00_scrptmanScripts_HiddenField=&__VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT=9&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section4%24ContractorsGrid%24ctl02%24tbPrice=0&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section1%24ddlQuoteType=&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section4%24ContractorsGrid%24ctl02%24tbName=&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section1%24txtMKSubContractor=0&__EVENTVALIDATION=Z%2B4HxHWchCRKUUGSyPU5%2FaMbJ3YqImwp6UvxZdFKa4s%2B%2BxMF%2FXQV9M9ulkv8hn2igRVXZTBrl8dCablkMQIj025VkKji2Y6Ur3hDKKIQ%2F%2B1JC4zbrPLuIFgQ8VIHorOTvfe1F1DfMfcWxPDAWCrwSlp%2Fy1xU%2ByRDktLppsOggXpSQDDQyX%2B0dFKSaPzDfUlGqxAQjzR%2FgB%2F730nz0B%2Ff6acYFY8hpPMIi3t0dGmPK6Hh5%2FpqGudw4zrwvl%2FBoXlmEtLCfGehgfsmn4vXRxgYlWD30M5hqQskYa8ljQQqA6H9%2FqSLi1vKaYuEDbSo%2F8uDrZPhUPQIjx9tY8Q%2FluSW7Mtlfw%2BgwK9I29%2F8VLmCmYZAs%2Fc9Xp0uyZIJ%2FTDE8g0UYXKfJUP9pydprX0%2FYXxEtbCE14rkNHaWQL2lDoxTmGIgSN8fWgQ%2B%2Bi0Dmw1EWoy2f9eSTggqYwskl6Po8bVvbk0ivncMGoy3b5H32wM6E4sxd5sztbm9gPBtmrM4tFEPxCktYJknpsRjEvkErVotyGWQjylFrGgQrGVCOSNI0ah7SVC51TKqGImZSMKrq1OUxA%2FCTaACsy5iz5DieWI170%2BTNtI%3D&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section1%24txtHelpdeskRef=&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section1%24txtQuoteDate=17%2F09%2F2021&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section1%24ddlContracts=0&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section3%24LabourGrid%24ctl02%24LabourRateType=0&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section1%24txtDescription=&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section5%24tbxComprehensiveC=&__LASTFOCUS=&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section1%24tbxBudgetType=&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section2%24MaterialsGrid%24ctl02%24tbDesc=&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section3%24LabourGrid%24ctl02%24LabourRateAmount=0&ctl00%24ctl00%24cphBaseContent%24CPH_Section3%24LabourGrid%24ctl02%24LabourType=0&__VIEWSTATE6=j2dj4ouRMqfNDIhs4Dq5Vuz1zC%2BGiQb5uOQNoICtq3sjeRXHwa5SjV4uXYpGE95rLleqPl%2Bd0Pn%2FObMHZrSk5EYqOyw6zeE79ftoqWwjw8cl2q9LoHNsf3Wqyc8DoVzNgMEGIWo6eDBnR

[Jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OJO9.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to extract the values with the following regular expression.

```
__VIEWSTATE([0-9]*)" id="__VIEWSTATE([0-9]*)" value="(.*?)"
```

[image]

Use the template `$3$` to extract the IDs.

> The template used to create a string from the matches found. This is an arbitrary string with special elements to refer to groups within the regular expression. The syntax to refer to a group is: '$1$' to refer to group 1, '$2$' to refer to group 2, etc. $0$ refers to whatever the entire expression matches.

You can get the VIEWSTATE IDs count with

```
${VIEWSTATE_matchNr}
```

or

```
vars.get("VIEWSTATE_matchNr")
```

> refName_matchNr - the number of matches found; could be 0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think using regular expression is the best idea to work with HTML data, maybe you should consider going for [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter/) instead?

   [image]
2. With regards to dynamically adding all these "viewstates" to your request it can be done only using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the following example code:

   ```
   1.upto(vars.get('viewstate_matchNr') as int, { counter ->
       sampler.addArgument('VIEWSTATE' + counter, vars.get("viewstate_" + counter))
   })
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]

---

Are you sure that this is not a functional issue? I haven't seen more than one [VIEWSTATE](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/225740/what-is-view-state-and-how-it-works-in-Asp-Net53/) parameter and 127 is way too much for me, normally developers store multiple values in a single viewstate if needed.